# Multiple-entry Bulgaria visa to enter to Romania

Tags: visas, romania, bulgaria

I got the Bulgaria multiple entry visa, can I enter Bucharest then pass the border to Bulgaria ?

If yes, what other document I have to prepare to show to the Romanian immigration?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, according to the [Romanian ministry of Foreign Affairs](http://www.mae.ro/en/node/2040). Just make sure you show them your Bulgarian visa as that grants you visa-free entry to Romania

> **V. Do I need a visa?**
>   **2. NO**
>
> [...]
>
> The holders of visas or residence permits issued by Bulgaria, Cyprus
>   or Croatia.